# Using constants and code in procedure calls (inno setup)

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

I tried calling a procedure from the `AfterInstall` method in Inno setup, but it gives me a syntax error. The section `{code:GetShortName|{app}}` is taken litterally. I tries using ExpandConstant, but I have the same error, the + operator does not seem to be liked there. I tried passing the whole thing in the ExpandConstant, but instead I get an error at runtime:

**"Internal error: Expression error 'Script error: Could not call proc.'"**.

```
Source: "InputFiles\prog.exe"; 
DestDir: "{tmp}/" ; 
AfterInstall: ExecuteCommand('{tmp}\prog.exe', '--distribute ' + ExpandConstant('{code:GetShortName|{app}}') + '/{#SandboxInternalFolder}')
```

How can I use the code and constant at this location?

Comment: It seems you're out of luck with the `+` concatenation operator there. You can narrow this problem simply by passing e.g. `'A' + 'B'` to an `AfterInstall` function with a single parameter. That concatenation for the parameter just prevents from compilation. Hard to say how to overcome this other way than defining as many parameters as you're passing or by defining yet another preprocessor variable.

Comment: If it's impossible to do so, I might create another custom procedure taking no parameters that will do the concatenation and call ExecuteCommand. The draw back is that I will need one procedure for each call to ExecuteCommand that needs to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parser for parameters for AfterInstall values is fairly primitive -- it can only cope with single values or a single string value wrapped in an ExpandConstant call.  You cannot use any expressions or other function calls.

There's still a way to write that particular construction though, due to the way that ExpandConstant works:

```
AfterInstall: ExecuteCommand(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\prog.exe'), ExpandConstant('--distribute {code:GetShortName|{app}}\{#SandboxInternalFolder}'))
```

Having said that, unless there's a really compelling reason to pass all that in as parameters, you should just specify a simple procedure name and do whatever you want in there directly.  And that way you can avoid expanding the code constant -- you can just call GetShortName directly too.

Comment: I ended up using a function with no parameter, which calls the Execute command function.

Comment: @Royi No.  And I'm not aware of any such trouble; you should ask a separate question if you think you've found something.